# CSS ::after selector wraps and moves text in my menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, css-float, css-selectors

Something has changed with the latest browsers (Chrome, Safari, IE) and I can't figure out why things look broken now.  The site I'm talking about is [here](http://www.dougkraft.com/) (the "Writing" menu), and I wasn't able to build a minimized fiddle for this problem (sorry).

I have a standard CSS based menu, built from unordered nested lists which show/hide on mouse hover.  For those submenus that have yet another menu, I use an automatically placed ">" character to indicate that.  This is the code:

```
ul.menu li.arrow > a::after {
  content: ">";
  float: right;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

So for those `<li>` elements that have another submenu (i.e. a nested `<ul>`) I want to automatically add the ">" right-aligned.  This worked until recently.  However, with some of the latest browser updates it seems that the ">" does not expand the width of the `<ul>` anymore but instead wraps around onto the next line.

[image]

I tried to somehow widen the `<ul>` (it's currently set to `width:auto`) but that didn't help; setting the `<li>` or the `<a>` inside the list item to `white-space:nowrap` didn't help either.  However, I noticed that when I remove the `float` then all ">" are there, just not nicely aligned to the right side.

How can I fix this?

Comment: This seems...suspect: "Something has changed with the latest browsers (Chrome, Safari, IE)"... what versions did you last notice this functioning in, and are you ABSOLUTELY CERTAIN none of the code changed?

Comment: I first noticed it when my friend updated his iPhone to the new iOS.  The website wasn't updated in a week or two.  In fact, the menu works on my Mac with Safari 5.1.10, did work with Chrome but not with the latest Chrome 31.0.1650.57.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `:before` instead of `:after`:

```
ul.menu li.arrow > a:before {
    content: ">";
    float: right;
    padding-left: 1em;
}
```

The problem is that floating elements can only affect following elements, but not previous ones.

But if you want some separation between `>` and the text, use

```
ul.menu li.arrow:before {
    content: ">";
    float: right;
}
ul.menu li.arrow > a {
    padding-right: 1em;
}
```

Comment: Just replacing `::after` with `::before` didn't quite work; however, your second proposal worked just fine! :)  Would you mind elaborating on your explanation of the float some more?  (Why this stopped working, I can only speculate that I had it wrong in the first place and a browser bug was fixed which exposed my wrong CSS?)

Comment: @Jens Weird, my first code works for me on Firefox 28. And yes, probably your code stopped working due to a browser bug, because the spec hasn't changed, so the behavior should be the same.